# How to add fields/members to the aspnet_user table/object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Following this question - [aspnet_Membership IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898022/aspnet-membership-ip-address), I am looking to add few more fields and data regarding my users (let's say phone number, age and favorite ice cream flavor...). For that, I'll need to use more than one field and therefore, the comment field is not enough.

Is it possible to add columns to aspnet_Users or aspnet_Membership tables and bind the values entered in the registration form to these columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ASP.NET profile provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead. There you can add what you want (for example a picture of the user, a custom start-page or his phone-number).

Here's recommandable reading: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx

Here's a sample from my web.config using an additional property for every user called `StartPage` with a `SqlProfileProvider` which automatically saves it in SQL-Server:

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ErpConnectionString" applicationName="/ERP"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="Startpage"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

I'm reading this user setting after he has logged in:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    String startPage = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("Startpage") as string;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(startPage))
    {
        Response.Redirect(startPage);
    }
}
```

You can save the value in following way:

```
HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("Startpage", startPage);
HttpContext.Current.Profile.Save();
```

Comment: I'm not sure i've understood the meaning of that. Do you have nice example for that? Also, am I supposed to run again aspnet_regsql.exe on my db, using the -Ap sign?

Comment: @Urik: Edited my answer to provide a sample.